# How to understand sum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that a sequence of $n$ 1’s and $m$ 0’s is randomly permuted so that each of the $(n + m)!/(n!m!)$ possible arrangements is equally likely. Any consecutive string of 1’s is said to constitute a run of 1’s—for instance, if n = 6, m = 4, and the ordering is 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, then there are 3 runs of 1’s—and we are interested in computing the mean number of such runs.

Let $I_i = 1$ if a run of $1$'s starts at $i$, $0$ otherwise.

Therefore, $R(1)$, the number of runs of 1, can be expressed as
$R(1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} I_i$.

This is a simple question from a textbook. If $I_1=1$, then $I_2=0$. Why can you add up dependent r.v.? I don't understand the last formula.

Comment: Try it on your example.  $I_i=1$ if $i\in\{1,5,9\}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about dependency. There is no problem in adding dependent random variables. For instance, if $X$ is a random variable, you surely agree that $X$ and $X$ are dependent, even though $2X = X + X$ is well-defined.

Dependence between random variables does say the following: If I have information about one variable, it will give me information about the other. Here is an example: Imagine you throw a penny independently 5 times. That will give you five **independent** random variables $X_1,\dots,X_5$ which are $1$ if you threw head and $0$ otherwise. Now look at $Y = X_1 + X_2$. Then $X_1$ and $Y$ are dependent. Indeed, if $X_1 = 1$, I know that $Y \geq 1$. But still, I can add $X_1$ and $Y$. What does it represent? Imagine the following. You have two friends and you promised to give friend $A$ one dollar if the first throw gives head and to give friend $B$ one dollar for each head in the two first throws. Then $Y + X_1$ is the total money you owe your friends.